# Get position from geography column

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sqlgeography

I'm migrating a table containing geographic information as latitude, longitude, to one using a geography column (in SQL server 2008).

I need to update a stored procedure which returns those values.

I can do this:

```
DECLARE @geog geography;
SET @geog = (SELECT [geography] FROM MyTable);

SELECT @g.STAsText();
```

but the signature for the SP, which I don't want to change, requires this:

```
@latitude [float] OUTPUT,
@longitude [float] OUTPUT
```

How do I get the right values, as floats?

I can use http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com.au/2007/09/sql-function-split.html or similar, but surely this shouldn't be that convoluted?

Thanks
Melanie

Comment: SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
SELECT @g.Lat;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = (SELECT [geography] FROM MyTable);

SELECT @g.Lat, @g.Long;
```